# What is the C# equivalent of VB.NET CType?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I've tried googling this and am also using the search feature on this site, but none of the answers I've found answer my question.

In Visual Basic, if I wanted an easy way to convert from one of my classes to another custom class, I can define the `CType` operator to define how to convert from one class to the other. I can then call `CType( fromObject, toNewType)` to do the conversion or in C# I guess you can just do a simple cast.

However, in C#, how do you define how the actual cast will be handled from one custom class to another to another custom class (like you can in Visual Basic using the `CType` operator)?

Comment: @kangkan  I see you changed my title to something more specific thanks. However, i spent 40 mins searching on that and nowhere did i see a reference to the csharp impliciit/explicit operators.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You *could* define a custom cast using the [explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx) keyword:

```
public static explicit operator TargetClass(SourceClass sc)
{
    return new TargetClass(...)
}
```

...but consider not doing that. It'll confuse the folks who will have to maintain your software down the line. Instead, just define a constructor for your target class, taking an instance of your source class as an argument:

```
public TargetClass(SourceClass sc)
{
    // your conversions
}
```

Comment: +1 because this is a valid way to convert from one object to another. But, I don't understand how using the `implicit` or `explicit` operators will confuse maintainers.  Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Jim: developers don't expect casts to do anything more than they do in 99.99% of all cases, especially for reference-type casts. They'll certainly be unprepared to deal with any exception other than `ClassCastException`. Principle of least surprise.

Comment: @Michael, I guess I understand your point.  To me, it makes sense to cast from, say, `Square` to `Rectangle` or `Celsius` to `Fahrenheit` but casting from one object to a dissimilar object doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Jim: it's a fine line. I like your examples, but I've seen too much excessive "cleverness" too.

Comment: thanks! And i agree that it could be confusing but i was reading a new book as refresher and realized i dint' totally understand this... and it got my little brain a going!

Comment: @Michael: excessive "cleverness" of other devs makes me want to stay home some days.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the [explicit operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx)

Example from MSDN:

```
// Must be defined inside a class called Farenheit:
public static explicit operator Celsius(Fahrenheit f)
{
    return new Celsius((5.0f / 9.0f) * (f.degrees - 32));
}

Fahrenheit f = new Fahrenheit(100.0f);
Console.Write("{0} fahrenheit", f.Degrees);
Celsius c = (Celsius)f;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to overload the [Cast operators](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0160__Operator-Overload/0220__Cast-operator.htm) on a class.

Comment: +1.  Although, I think the `implicit` operator can be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any specific code for conversion, `System.Convert` methods are closest to `CType` in Visual Basic. Otherwise, it can be seen in light of some example like:

VB.NET

```vb
Dim btn As Button = CType(obj, Button)
```

C# Equivalent:

```csharp
Button btn = (Button)obj
```

or

```csharp
Button btn = obj as Button
```